# Want to hide ag-grid on first component load

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

As my requirement i want to hide the ag-grid on angular component load, based on customer value selection from drop down it call apis & load with the api data into the ag-grid.

in short initially if no data then not to display whole grid, empty doesn't look nice

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping it with a simple `*ngIf` and see if the grid still loads right.

If that doesn't work, the next easiest thing would be to wrap it in an element with css that makes it hidden/changes height to 0 until the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can use **ngIf** directive something like this -

Let consider that your **ag-grid** component is `<app-ag-grid></app-ag-grid>` and **customerData** is an array which contains data of customer.

Now use it as -

`<app-ag-grid *ngIf="customerData.length > 0"> </app-ag-grid>`

Hope it helps.